# Tableau Other Databases (JDBC) Connection to SAS datasets

Tags: jdbc, sas, tableau-api

I am trying to get an Other Databases (JDBC) connection from Tableau to SAS using SAS' integrated object model (sasiom jdbc) but running into this error:

**Error:**

```
Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
Trying to connect an http1.x server
Generic JDBC connection error
Trying to connect an http1.x server
```

**Configuration Details**

I believe my configuration is somewhat correct so far but I think that Tableau is not identifying the correct driver class to use when making a JDBC connection to SAS.

***At a high level here is what a JDBC connection to SAS looks like:***

- JDBC Connection String: `jdbc:sasiom://companyserver.company.com:port`
- Driver class name: `com.sas.rio.MVADriver`
- Driver jar files location for Tableau to access: `C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers`

---

In this extract below from the Tableau Desktop logs it looks like 'dialect' and 'class' being used are **genericjdbc** which I think I want the class to be **com.sas.rio.MVADriver** to use the classname for sasiom but I'm not certain

```
{"attributes":{":protocol-customizations":"","class":"genericjdbc","dbname":"","dialect":"genericjdbc","jdbcproperties":"","jdbcurl":"jdbc:sasiom://companyserver.company.com:8591","password":"***","schema":"","username":"username","warehouse":""},"closed-protocols-count":"0","connection-limit":"16","group-id":"3","in-construction-count":"0","protocols-count":"0","this":"0x0000018511611140"}}
```

---

**Properties file attempted without success**

I've tried to add a properties file to force the class to be com.sas.rio.MVADriver in the hopes that I get a connection successful or at least a different error if anything else needs to change but no luck with a properties file.

Please provide some help or direction if anyone has successfully created a custom JDBC connection in Tableau and how you got it working? What configuration steps am I missing?

**Is there a way to verify that Tableau is using the correct driver class for the jdbc connection? I have not seen the correct class of com.sas.rio.MVADriver referenced at all in the Tableau logs**

Comment: I'd worry about the path to the jar file: "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers". Can you try the variant that has no space? Usually it is C:/progra~1/Tableau/Drivers. Or put the jar containing the jdbc driver in some other place on your disk that has no space in the name.

Comment: @KyleDyer - I can see in the Tableau logs that the jar files are recognized and listed out, so the path to the jar files is okay. I suspect that this http1.x error is proxy related after doing a general search for that term. Digging into that with the Tableau support team. Will post an answer once we have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is a Type 4.0 JDBC Driver is needed to automatically register the driver class name with the JDBC driver manager. The public SAS .jar files contain a Type 2.0 JDBC Driver which requires a manual JDBC driver class specification, which Tableau does not allow to my knowledge. It appears this is not possible currently.